# Python - Pick from Array based on price with a caveat

Tags: python, arrays

I'm relatively new to Python and have already written a code to randomly select from two tables based on user input but the next function I need to create is more complex and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.

I'm going to have some code that's going to take user input and generate an amount of money I'm going to add to a variable, lets say, wallet.

I then want to write some code that takes random objects from an array based on price.

Now here's the caveat(s).  Lets say array A is chosen.  In Array A there will be 3-4 other sub arrays.  Within those arrays are 4 objects first, second, third, and fourth.  With the first being the cheapest and the fourth being the most expensive.  I want this code to NOT be able to buy object second without having bought object first.  I don't want an object purchasable unless the prerequisite is also purchased.

I'm just having a hard time thinking it through (a weakness in general in programming I need to overcome) but any advice or links to a concept similar to what I'm aiming to do would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't a [good fit for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As your question is more conceptual it may be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com. It may be closed and/or migrated because of this.

Comment: @MattH when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat I'll bear that in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it might be enough to have a counter associated with each sub-array as to how many of the items in that sub-array have already been bought.  Give that you haven't shown any details as to your representation of these things, I can't give more details as to how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you're getting at, because you're not expressing your ideas very well. You're finding this general programming difficult as programming can be considered as the precise expression of ideas.

So, in very general terms you are trying to simulate some sort of curated shopping experience. You need to:

- Track a value of currency.
- Manage a product catalogue.
- Allow a selection of products based on value and constraints based on prior selections.

If I were doing this, I might write a class that I'd use to manage the basket. I might instantiate a basket with a budget figure and a product catalogue to select from. I might express the constraints in the catalogue, but enforce them in the basket.

I would probably use the basket (budget, tally and selections) to filter the product catalogue to highlight eligible products.

If multiple transactions are allowed, the basket would need to have knowledge of previous purchases and therefore which prerequisites have already been fulfilled.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
def can_buy(wanted, for_sale, bought):
    return (wanted in for_sale and
            wanted not in bought and
            wanted == for_sale[len(bought)] and
            bought == for_sale[:len(bought)])
```

You can use it like:

```
>>> for_sale = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> bought = [1, 2]
>>> can_buy(3, for_sale, bought)
True
>>> can_buy(4, for_sale, bought)
False
```

Comment: I like that True/False you have there.  I think I can implement that into the code I'm making.